# Now, if $u\in C([0,1])$, prove that $d(x,N) = \inf_{n\in N}||u-n|| = |\bar{u}|$ where $|\bar{u}| = \int_0^1 u(x) dx$ is the mean of u.

Tags: real-analysis

The question is the following:

> Consider $C([0,1])$ with the $\sup$-norm. Let 
>   $$N = \bigg\{ f\in C([0,1]) | \int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0\bigg\}$$
>   be the closed linear subspace of $C([0,1])$ of functions with zero mean. Let 
>   $$X = \{ f\in C([0,1]) | f(0) = 0\}$$ and define $M = N\cap X$, meaning that
>   $$M = \bigg\{ f\in C([0,1]) | f(0) = 0,  \int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0\bigg\}.$$
>   Now, if $u\in C([0,1])$, prove that 
>   $$d(u,N) = \inf_{n\in N}||u-n|| = |\bar{u}|$$
>   where $|\bar{u}| = |\int_0^1 u(x) dx|$ is the mean of u, so the infimum is attained when $n = u-\bar{u}\in N$.

I actually  have no idea how to approach this. How both sides of the equation related? I tried to apply the mean value theorem, but it didn't work. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What's the relevance of $M$? its defined but never used? I guess $d(x,N)$ should be $d(u,N)$? PS it should be $|\bar u | = \left| \int_0^1 u(x) dx \right| $, its possible that $\bar u< 0$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry, the definition of $M$ is used in the second question. I just typed up the first one.

Comment: No problem, no harm done :) Have you read my hint?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks! Let me take a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strong hint. On the one hand, since $u-\bar u \in N$, $$d(u,N) \le \|u-(u-\bar u)\| = |\bar u| .$$
Conversely, we want to prove that $|\bar u| \le d(u,N)$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary, and let $n\in N$ be such that $\|u-n\|\le d(u,N) + \epsilon$. Then

$$|\bar u| = \left|\int_0^1 u(x) \, \text dx \right| = \left|\int_0^1 u(x) -n(x) \, \text dx\right| \le \dots $$

Conclude by the arbitrariness of $\epsilon>0$.

PS no clue what $M$ is for...

Comment: I do think I got most of them. One thing confuses me right now is that how the choice of $n$ is legit as you wrote:" let $n \in N$ be such that $||u-n|| \leq d(u,N) + \epsilon$." Or is it just a rewrite of the infimum?

Comment: @UnbelieveTable yes exactly, for any set $A$, $a = \inf A$ iff there is a sequence $a_n  \in A $ such that $a_n$ decreases to $a$ (so for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $a_n$ with $0< a_n - a < \epsilon$)

Comment: ...that's not an iff. An iff would have to be more carefully worded, sorry about that, hope it didnt confuse you! @UnbelieveTable